Set ZingChart Legend Items height individually
I am using ZingChart to create a PieChart. I am having problems with the legend. One of my series (pie slice) has a multiline legendText while the other two have a standard one-line legendText. This messes up the legend because now all three items have a huge height and thus creating unnecessary empty space between the legend items and thus making the whole legend way too tall.
Here is my config:
{
  graphset: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      plotarea: {
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0
      },
      series: [
        {
          values: [100000],
          legendText: 'ITEM1'
        },
        {
          values: [550000],
          legendText: 'ITEM2\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline'
        },
        {
          values: [20000],
          legendText: 'ITEM3'
        }
      ],
      scaleR: { // set starting point at the top
        refAngle: 270 // relative to the starting 90 degree position.
      },
      legend: {
        adjustLayout: true,
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        layout: 'x1',
        borderWidth: 0,
        alpha: 0,
        marker: {
          type: 'square'
        },
      }
    },
  ]
}

and here is the resulting plot:

Notice the large space between the legend items 1 and 2. How can I get rid of this?
How can I solve this issue?

Use layout:float to prevent the legend entries from spreading too far apart and add some height on the legend > item property as I've done in this demo.


Thanks for the info. This is a good workaround but I would prefer to have the items in a single column. But for now it's the best working solution.
